# EOFException is thrown when reading contents of an ePub file

Tags: android, epub, epublib

I'm trying to read the contents of an ePub file using the library epublib and this [example](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android) demonstrates that.

For me, an exception is thrown when loading the book from the input stream

```
// Load Book from inputStream
Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
```

Not sure why the code isn't working and the exception is thrown for me? It has worked for other users of the StackOverflow.

Full Stack trace is shared below:

```
W/System.err: java.io.EOFException
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:235)
W/System.err:     at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readResources(EpubReader.java:184)
W/System.err:     at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:94)
W/System.err:     at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:53)
W/System.err:     at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:37)
W/System.err:     at com.blogspot.gsrikar.ePubViewerActivity.readEPubContents(ePubViewerActivity.java:102)
W/System.err:     at com.blogspot.gsrikar.ePubViewerActivity.onCreate(ePubViewerActivity.java:88)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Did you try more than one book file? Are you sure your epub file(s) are properly formatted (readable)? Did you use the right name? Does the file exist?...

Comment: Please, check both file location/ directory and file extension.

Comment: It is not very wise to waste 100 reputation points for a bounty, but then not provide enough information but just a single line of code. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with source code, a download link for the EPUB in question and what else could be helpful. Help the community help you, otherwise you will get no meaningful answer.

Answer (score 3):

**EOFException** is thrown:

- if there is no data in a **stream** but you are trying to read.. eg read
  methods of chain streams like DataInputStream, ObjectInputStream
  throw **EOFException** if they are trying to read from FileInputStream
  but the FileInputStream is empty or
- if the formats are not matching...eg if int is present and you are
  using readFloat() of DataInputStream

Answer (score 0):

You should try calling below method before passing it to readEpub.
Java Doc link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()

```
//assuming the above variables are already declared.
if(epubInputStream.available() > 0)
    Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
else
    System.out.println("no data to read");
```